# Why does facebook use TCP for SET and UDP for GET in memcached

Tags: caching, memcached, key-value

My question is regarding memcached. Facebook uses memcached as a cache for their structured data to reduce the latency for their users.  They have optimized performance of memcached with UDP on linux. http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=39391378919

But interestingly they still use TCP for set operations but use UDP for get operation.

Why would they be doing so? I mean why not use UDP for set operation also? UDP scales better than TCP because of reduced states that need to be maintained in the operating system.

Thanks,

Comment: They want to make sure the data they receive is properly error checked but don't give a damn if you get their data correctly or not?

Comment: As long as set is performed hundred times less frequent than get - does it really make big sense?

Comment: @CoreyOgburn Both TCP and UDP have checksums. What TCP does is flow control. If you lose a packed TCP can retransmit the packet whereas in UDP the whole data has to be retransmitted.

Comment: @zerkms Yes set is performe 100 times less frequent than get but then why use TCP for that?

Comment: @hobyist: because lost set packets lead to performance degradation and even incorrect cache state (as long as cache won't be invalidated when it need to be), and several lost get's doesn't?

Answer (score 6):

This sentence pretty much uncovers the problem and the solution:

> Although we improved the memory efficiency with TCP, we moved to UDP
>   for get operations to reduce network traffic and implement
>   application-level flow control for multi-gets (gets of hundreds of
>   keys in parallel).

TCP is also flow control and in case of Memcache *multi-gets* it is pretty serial. You open the connection (or pool it), query list of keys, wait and then get result with list of all values. Instead they implemented the application-level flow control themselves on top of connection-less parallel UDP *gets*. Here are benefits of UDP I see for FB sized software:

- no need to open connections, pooling them, doing additional round-trips, sessions, handshakes, keep-alives and so on;
- multiple distributed Memcache servers and indexes can be queried in parallel which is fine in the spirit of micro-services and "micro-caches" as services;
- can multicast UDP packet to provide high-availability with redundancy, load balancing, dynamic routing or even sharding - the first response wins!
- individual *get* time-out and retry policy may be implemented on application level;
- the logic can be executed as soon as any partially complete data is available - no need to wait for the complete *multi-get* result;

On the other hand I think they do writes over TCP for consistency. TCP with memcached provides a transaction where request is sent and then response acknowledges the cache update. Reimplementing that in UDP wouldn't provide much benefits I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

Each UDP datagram contains a simple frame header, followed by data in the
same format as the TCP protocol described above. In the current
implementation, requests must be contained in a single UDP datagram, but
responses may span several datagrams. (The only common requests that would
span multiple datagrams are huge multi-key `get` requests and `set`
requests, both of which are more suitable to TCP transport for reliability
reasons anyway.)

https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the best way to understand packet lost.
For example when you use facebook chat,you will understand if a sentence is not received but you can't understand this in Ymsg.